# Error en ASP.NET MVC - does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Compra'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hola tengo un problema en el cual al momento de ejecutar la vista me da un error en el controlador diciendo que

> Compra' does not declare a navigation property with the name
>   'Compra'.'

Estoy haciendo la unión de dos tablas de compras y cliente pero ya lo intente arreglar pero sigue dándome el mismo problema  ya le intente cambiándole de nombre pero nada no se que me este faltando o si no lo estoy mandando llamar bien estoy usando asp.net en c# y sql server este es mi controlador.

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            using (VistasContext dbModel = new VistasContext())
            {
                var persona = dbModel.Compra.Include("Compra").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id ==1);
                var nombres = persona.Cliente.Compras;
                return View(dbModel.Cliente.ToList());
            }
        }
```

y mis modelos

```
 public class Compra
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Productos { get; set; }
        public double Precio { get; set; }
        public Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    }
```

y

```
   public int MatriculaCliente { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }
        public string Telefono { get; set; }

        public List<Compra> Compras { get; set; }
    }
```

y mi vista

```
@model IEnumerable<VistasParciales_2.Models.Cliente> 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}    
<h2>Index</h2>   
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MatriculaCliente)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nombre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Edad)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Telefono)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>    
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MatriculaCliente)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Edad)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Telefono)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Necesitas crear un ViewModel donde juntes ambas clases en primer lugar, en segundo lugar agrega la palabra `virtual` para la navegación entre clases.

Comment: Esto te ayudará https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te falta elaborar mejor tu pregunta. si quieres la respuesta a tu error esta en esta linea.

```
var persona = dbModel.Compra.Include("Compra").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id ==1);
```

Estas haciendo una consulta en la tabla compra. y después buscas un campo "compra", pero ya estas en esa tabla. por lo que deberías de cambiarlo como sigue:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (VistasContext dbModel = new VistasContext())
        {
            var Compra = dbModel.Compra.Include("Cliente").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id ==1);
            var nombres = Compra.Cliente.Nombre; //no se como tengas la tabla cliente, no la agregaste
            return View(dbModel.Cliente.ToList()); //no estas regresando el nombre ni nada... te falta algo?
        }
    }
```